# Why does Restsharp include too many backslashes on Response.Content?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I'm using Restsharp v105.2.3 on asp.net MVC.

My code below

```
var client = new RestClient()
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://sample.com/");
var request = new RestRequest("api/users", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

return response.Content;
```

Instead of returning json string like this

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"testuser\"}]"
```

It adds more backslashes into the json string

```
"\"[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"testuser\\\"}]\""
```

Which makes deserializing difficult. I've also tested doing the same request using Postman, and it returns the json like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"testuser"}]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: How do you create the json data? Do you have a controller method that return a string type that you construct? Also, you say Postman returns the json fine. What exactly do you mean? You mean in Postman it shows as `"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"testuser\"}}]"`?

Comment: I have a Web API that create a json string from a datatable (which is requested from a database). This Restsharp request access the controller inside that Web API. Postman returns it like this `[{"id":"1","name":"testuser"}]`

Comment: And the signature of the web api method returns a string? Does it look something like this? `public string Get()`

Comment: Not exactly that, it's `public IActionResult Get()` which returns Http status code along with the content, `return Ok(json)`; in this case the content is string.

Comment: Not sure but I guess `Ok(json)` expects an object and it serializes it to json. When you pass it a serialized json string it serializes it again which results a double serialization... Anyway try to find how to pass it a serialized string or use another way that supports serialized strings and not objects

Comment: Okay I'll check if the Web API does double serialization. Also actually I have another client (written in Java) which also access the same API, but it reads and deserialize the returned json without problem. Is it because the one on java can deserialize a double serialized string?